# How to remove specific handler socket.io swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io, swift2

I have these handlers:

```
socket.on("one") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
    //code
}

socket.on("two") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
    //code
}

socket.on("three") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
    //code
}

socket.on("four") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
    //code
}
```

How do I remove just the "three" handler without `socket.removeAllHandlers` and start all over again?

Comment: `socket.off("three")`

Comment: @dan Thanks, was that.. :/